# Can anyone help me with this error

Tags: yii

```
if (isset($_POST['Software'])) {
            $_POST['Software']['sw_icon'] = $model->sw_icon;
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Software'];
            $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'sw_icon');
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Software'];
            $model->updated_date = date("Y-m-d H:i"); 
            if ($model->save()) {
                if (!empty($uploadedFile)) {  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                    $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../images/software_icons/' . $model->sw_icon);
                }
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Software updated successfully.');
                $this->redirect(array('index'));
            }
        }
```

When I use the above code i get the following error

> ...`move_uploaded_file():` The second argument to `copy()` function
>   cannot be a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me the result of `Yii::app()->basePath . '/../images/software_icons/' . $model->sw_icon`,seems like it a directory

Answer (score 0):

You can move a file to another file name. You can't move a file to a folder.
Try replace `Yii::app()->basePath . '/../images/software_icons/' . $model->sw_icon` on
this: `Yii::app()->basePath . '/../images/software_icons/newfile'`